# Evaluating a Complex Integral Using the Principal Branch

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Evaluate

$$\int_\Gamma\frac{2z}{1+z^2}dz$$

where $\Gamma$ is any contour from $z_1=\dfrac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $z_2=\dfrac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$ in the half plane $\operatorname{Re} z>0$.

So naturally, looking at this integral, it's already in the form which we can easily recognize as $\log{1+z^2}$ being the anti derivative. So, is it just straight forward to evaluating this from $z_1\to z_2$. They lie on the same vertical line on the real axis.

$$\log{1+z^2}\Big|_{z_1}^{z_2}=\log{(\frac{1+2i-1}{2}+1)}-\log{(\frac{1-2i-1}{2}+1)}=\log{(i+1)}-\log{(-i+1)}=?$$

I just want to make sure I'm not over or underthinking this problem. Moving forward, we have that the statement above is equal to

$$\log{\Big[(\frac{1+i}{1-i})\cdot(\frac{1+i}{1+i})\Big]}=\log{\frac{2i}{2}}=\log{i}=\log{|i|}+i\operatorname{Arg}{i}\implies$$

$$|i|=\sqrt{1^2}=1, \operatorname{Arg}{i}=\arcsin{1}=\frac{\pi}{2}\implies$$

$$\int_\Gamma\frac{2z}{1+z^2}dz=\log{1}+i\frac{\pi}{2}=\boxed{i\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

Is this correct, and is there a faster way to evaluate this integral?

Answer (score 1):

Yes your answer is correct. Read on to see how I get it.

When you're dealing with logarithms, you should know that only the imaginary part is multivalued. You should therefore have no issue finding the real part of $\ln(1+i)-\ln(1-i)$.

Now to tackle the imaginary part. Thus should be the difference between the arguments, but which arguments do you use?

**Keep your eyes on the road**

Let us start by factoring the argument of the logarithm, $1+z^2$, as $(z+i)(z-i)$. We can then consider each factor separately.

Imagine that you begin by facing $(1-i)/\sqrt2$ from the point $z=-i$. You turn in such a way that your eyes, looking straight ahead, remain focused on the contour. You are then looking along a vector that represents the factor $z+i$. If the contour stays in the right half-plane $\Re(z)>0$ as instructed in the problem, it recedes steadily to your left. Thus by the time you are facing $(1+i)/\sqrt2$ at the end of the contour, you've made a net counterclockwise turn, but this turn is linited to between $0°$and $90°$, thus between $0$ and $+\pi/2$ radians. That turn corresponds to the change in argument of the factor $z+i$ along the integration path.

Similarly, you find that the argument of $1-i$ changes by a difference beyween $0$ and $+\pi/2$ radians. So the argument of the whole product changes by an amount between $0$ and $\pi$, and since the actual difference must be $\pi/2+2k\pi$ for some integer $k$ (why?), the change in argument must be precisely $\pi/2$. The imaginary part of your logarithmic difference follow from that.

Comment: This intuitively makes sense. I like this conceptual description. So when we talk about $\log$(maybe only special cases) and the angles of a contour, we're really discussing the physical shape of the contour.